# Cipher puzzle with two strings of numbers

Tags: cipher

The two strings below describe the same English word:

7415963852

1475369963

**What word is it?**

Just for fun!

Credits: Hindemburg Melão Jr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word might be

> [Ni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_Who_Say_%22Ni!%22)

Reasoning

> Look at what the first string of digits traces out on a ten-digit keypad arranged as follows
>  [image]
>  The first seven digits **7415963** give a capital **N** and the last three digits **852** give a capital **I**.
>  The same can be said of the second string but applied to a ten-digit keypad with the following formation
>  [image]

Comment: Almost!!!! I take my hat to your reasoning skills.

Comment: Gurl ner ab ybatre gur Xavtugf Jub Fnl Av! Zhfg unir orra n erq UREEVAT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: I have no idea what this means, user MacGyver88! Please tell me?

Comment: Sorry, @Vinícius. It's referencing a movie that uses that word. .... And I just noticed the hyperlink in the answer. So, my excitement feels more like embarrassment for being too late to the party. LOL

Comment: Unless you mean rot13(). Take what I wrote and rotate each letter by 13 letters to get the hidden text. It's a normal thing around here.

Comment: @MacGyber88, don't forget to explicitly state rot13 before you type it, since some users might be new to the site